# Java script function to hold until save evenet execution is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a javascript function. In thi function i am calling a button event like below.

```
$("#btnSave").trigger("click");
```

My query is , Is there any way to keep the control here on this line until the saving is done?
 I have some code written underneath this line and it is being overridden.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show the code. Question does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have helped if you've posted some code.

You can do it in 2 ways:

1.) Use polling. After the trigger call use a loop to check for a flag that you must set when the save is complete. A timeout is needed for saving CPU from intensive js processing.

2.) Put the code to be executed after the trigger call inside a function. Pass this function as a callback to the onClick function.

```
    function onSaveClick(e) {
        //do my save stuff

        e.data.callback();
    }
```

No. 2 is recommended.
    //attach onclick event
    $("#btnSave").click(onSaveClick);

```
//you onclick function
function onSaveClick(event, callback) {
    //save data
    callback();
}

//trigger
$("#btnSave").trigger("click", afterSave);

//after save stuff
function afterSave(){
//do more stuff
}
```

Comment: What is e here ? I mean by button event is not showing e.data

Comment: "e" is the event passed to the event callback.
You must set the callback when you assign the "click" event:
$("mybutton").click({callback:"myAfterSaveFunction"} ,myOnButtonClickFunction);

Comment: sorry , not getting can you explain it more.

Comment: myAfterSaveFunction is a java script function ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a callback.

Get the lines under the trigger line and pass to your save function as callback when the event has success.

Comment: you mean i should shift the java script code in .cs file? as save event is in .cs file. Please explain again if i misunderstood something.

Comment: When you trigger your save button, something is done. I'm thinking you are using and AJAX request to save your changes. But if a regular POST, you just need to return false in the button click event and no action will be performed. Can you better explain your situation?

Comment: Yes, Save is happening under Ajax request. how can i return false from save click event. I mean "$("#btnSave").trigger("click");
" this line is sending control to .cs file once all the underneath java script code is executed. I can see that javascript code underneath effecting the UI but the save event is sending control once all java script code is executed so the UI changes are doing rollbacked.

Comment: Take a look in this documentation about jQuery promise: http://api.jquery.com/promise/ will help you to understand. The event from ajax run async with your code. You can configure to run sync but will make the browser stop working until the you get return it's not a good way to do that.